Removing chapter number in novel class template
I am writing a document using a template that uses the novel class:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/lix-novel-template/shnjdvjrpjtd
The template adds "CHAPTER 1" (2, 3, 4...) before the chapter title, both at the beginning of the chapter and as a running head on top of each page within the chapter. I would like to remove the CHAPTER 1 part and only keep the chapter title.


The chapter title code looks like this:
\h{Lorem}

Adding an asterisk does remove the numbering in the table of contents, but causes the title from the previous chapter to be used for the running head. If I add an asterisk for the first chapter, then "CHAPTER 0 CONTENTS" appears as the running head.
\h*{Lorem}

The template contains 3 files: lix.sty, main.tex and novel.cls. Both lix.sty and novel.cls contain code related to headers and headings, so I am not sure where the relevant code is.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

This is an issue that arises using the template that I linked.

Please include a test document in your question here, not as link. This will ensure that your questions remains useful for future users even if the link stops working.

I do not know how to create a minimal working example that still presents the issue.

see minimal working example (MWE) for some tips

I am aware of that, thank you.

Just before the \begin{document}, add
\fancyhead[C]{\small\scshape\color{darkgray} \leftmark}% l62 in novel.cls
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{% l47 in novel.cls
    \normalsize%
}{% Prefix.
    \relax % no prefix
}{% Vertical space between.
    0pt% no space added
}{% Chapter name.
    \centering\LARGE\bfseries\scshape%
}

This redefines commands written in the novel.cls
